# Entering fullscreen causes internal exceptions

Tags: directx, directx-11

When I use Alt+Enter or call `IDXGISwapChain::SetFullscreenState` I notice DirectX throws a bunch of exceptions internally. These occur if, and only if, I'm using a multisample count greater than 1 when I configure the `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC`

```
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018CC58.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018D854.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018D980.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018EBD8.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018ED8C.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018CC58.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018D854.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018D980.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018EBD8.
Exception thrown at 0x7412D8A8 in 05 - D3D11 Core App.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x0018ED8C.
```

These never propagate up to my code, so I'm assuming these messages are for first chance exceptions that are being handled.

My question is: are these messages normal or do they indicate I'm doing something in a non-ideal way?

For context, I'm working through Frank Luna's DirectX 11 book. This occurs in his own sample code for the Box Demo from chapter 6. The relevant code from his website:

```cpp
bool D3DApp::InitDirect3D()
{
    // Create the device and device context.

    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
            0,                 // default adapter
            md3dDriverType,
            0,                 // no software device
            createDeviceFlags,
            0, 0,              // default feature level array
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
            &md3dDevice,
            &featureLevel,
            &md3dImmediateContext);

    if( FAILED(hr) )
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"D3D11CreateDevice Failed.", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    if( featureLevel != D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0 )
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"Direct3D Feature Level 11 unsupported.", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }

    // Check 4X MSAA quality support for our back buffer format.
    // All Direct3D 11 capable devices support 4X MSAA for all render
    // target formats, so we only need to check quality support.

    HR(md3dDevice->CheckMultisampleQualityLevels(
        DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 4, &m4xMsaaQuality));
    assert( m4xMsaaQuality > 0 );

    // Fill out a DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC to describe our swap chain.

    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
    sd.BufferDesc.Width  = mClientWidth;
    sd.BufferDesc.Height = mClientHeight;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    sd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    sd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    // Use 4X MSAA?
    if( mEnable4xMsaa )
    {
        sd.SampleDesc.Count   = 4;
        sd.SampleDesc.Quality = m4xMsaaQuality-1;
    }
    // No MSAA
    else
    {
        sd.SampleDesc.Count   = 1;
        sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    }

    sd.BufferUsage  = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    sd.BufferCount  = 1;
    sd.OutputWindow = mhMainWnd;
    sd.Windowed     = true;
    sd.SwapEffect   = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    sd.Flags        = 0;

    // To correctly create the swap chain, we must use the IDXGIFactory that was
    // used to create the device.  If we tried to use a different IDXGIFactory instance
    // (by calling CreateDXGIFactory), we get an error: "IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain:
    // This function is being called with a device from a different IDXGIFactory."

    IDXGIDevice* dxgiDevice = 0;
    HR(md3dDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void**)&dxgiDevice));

    IDXGIAdapter* dxgiAdapter = 0;
    HR(dxgiDevice->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIAdapter), (void**)&dxgiAdapter));

    IDXGIFactory* dxgiFactory = 0;
    HR(dxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&dxgiFactory));

    HR(dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChain(md3dDevice, &sd, &mSwapChain));

    ReleaseCOM(dxgiDevice);
    ReleaseCOM(dxgiAdapter);
    ReleaseCOM(dxgiFactory);

    // The remaining steps that need to be carried out for d3d creation
    // also need to be executed every time the window is resized.  So
    // just call the OnResize method here to avoid code duplication.

    OnResize();

    return true;
}
```

---

```cpp
void D3DApp::OnResize()
{
    assert(md3dImmediateContext);
    assert(md3dDevice);
    assert(mSwapChain);

    // Release the old views, as they hold references to the buffers we
    // will be destroying.  Also release the old depth/stencil buffer.

    ReleaseCOM(mRenderTargetView);
    ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilView);
    ReleaseCOM(mDepthStencilBuffer);


    // Resize the swap chain and recreate the render target view.

    HR(mSwapChain->ResizeBuffers(1, mClientWidth, mClientHeight, DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, 0));
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer;
    HR(mSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&backBuffer)));
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(backBuffer, 0, &mRenderTargetView));
    ReleaseCOM(backBuffer);

    // Create the depth/stencil buffer and view.

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;

    depthStencilDesc.Width     = mClientWidth;
    depthStencilDesc.Height    = mClientHeight;
    depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthStencilDesc.Format    = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;

    // Use 4X MSAA? --must match swap chain MSAA values.
    if( mEnable4xMsaa )
    {
        depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count   = 4;
        depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = m4xMsaaQuality-1;
    }
    // No MSAA
    else
    {
        depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count   = 1;
        depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    }

    depthStencilDesc.Usage          = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthStencilDesc.BindFlags      = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags      = 0;

    HR(md3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, 0, &mDepthStencilBuffer));
    HR(md3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(mDepthStencilBuffer, 0, &mDepthStencilView));


    // Bind the render target view and depth/stencil view to the pipeline.

    md3dImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &mRenderTargetView, mDepthStencilView);


    // Set the viewport transform.

    mScreenViewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    mScreenViewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    mScreenViewport.Width    = static_cast<float>(mClientWidth);
    mScreenViewport.Height   = static_cast<float>(mClientHeight);
    mScreenViewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    mScreenViewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    md3dImmediateContext->RSSetViewports(1, &mScreenViewport);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ exceptions here are internal to the runtime, and do not propogate out of the function. Unless the `HRESULT` is coming back with an error, ignore them.